# Javascript Reg Ex Matching

Tags: javascript, regex, match

If I want to match() a string with the following pattern:

12345678_12345678

What would the reg ex look like for that?

(In other words, any 8 digit number, followed by and underscore, followed by another 8 digit number.)

Comment: have you tried anything yet? this is a pretty simple regex if you look through any basic documentation

Comment: @squint Thank you for the link. I realize in retrospect that in this case I was not as diligent in working through the problem on my own, as I usually am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
/^\d{8}_\d{8}$/
```

- `/` are used as a RegExp literal delimiter
- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `\d{8}` matches `8` numbers between `0` and `9`
- `_` matches the underscore character
- `$` matches the end of the string

I recommend reading through the [MDN documentation on RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)